# SNES usb controller adapter - some input not recognized

Tags: raspbian, gamepad, retropie

I just received the [Retro Link SNES Controller USB adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BYH9Q4Y) I ordered to use with RetroPie, however upon launching EmulationStation, the "Up" button and the "left" button on my snes controller is not recognized during configuration.

I plugged it in on my laptop, and tested every button with Windows' game controller setup, and everything is working fine.

Is there any way I can get my controller/adapter working properly on my Raspberry? Any drivers I can install?

I'm rather unfamiliar with Raspberry / Raspbian, so any help would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

`lsusb` outputs :

```
 Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp.
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1a6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
 Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
 Bus 001 Device 004: ID 040b:2000 Weltrend Semiconductor
 Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1292:5346 Innomedia
```

---

**EDIT 2**

I ran `jstest`, every button worked except "up" and "left", just like in EmulationStation.

Comment: Are you able to post what lsusb typed into the terminal says. This will show weather the gamepad is being detected by the Pi.

Comment: @Ryanteck I've added it to my post.

Comment: Have you tried your controller in a 'regular' Debian distribution to see if it works there? Live CD from their website.

Comment: @user2301728 Downloading it now, i'll update my post once i've tried it out.

Comment: @user2301728 I can't seem to get the Live CD working. I may have downloaded a wrong version, as my Pi won't boot. Can someone provide the link to the file I should have downloaded?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, burn it to a disk, and run it on your computer to see if it will work there.  This will let us know if it is a raspberian problem, or a larger linux problem.

Comment: @user2301728 The buttons worked on Debian, however I ran it through a virtual machine (I don't know if that makes a difference). I'm looking to see if I can use a different OS on my Pi that would work with my controller and adapter, but i'm not sure what's available.

Comment: It shouldn't.. That was my only thought... Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The new Linux kernels (Raspbian is Linux) have better support for game controllers. You may be interested in downloading and compiling your own custom kernel with all of the new drivers. Also, this Linux article (http://www.linux.org/article/view/joystick-and-other-game-controllers) may help you.